# Accuracy of the answers for Amazon Mechanical Turk workers

Tags: mechanicalturk, bibliography

Do you know any reference in the bibliography that reports a study on the accuracy of the answers of the (paid) workers in AMT?

I would like to find some statistics on the number of correct answers and understand whether they act as experts or not.

I found [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-011-0124-6#page-1) only reference.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is really going to depend on what exactly you're asking them to do. They're generally not experts.

Comment: Let's say very simple tasks, e.g., labeling and classification of text and images.

Comment: I'd say very high, especially for "masters" qualification holders...best way for any specific task, though, is to just try it out and see if you're happy with the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need numbers and I cannot try it since I live in Europe and the submission of tasks is limited to American users. I was wondering whether there are some existing studies about this that I can reference.